# How to change windows exe file's icon in linux without wine?

Tags: linux, windows, exe, embedded-resource

I know I can use [ResHacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to change a resource from windows and I know I can use [ResourceUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to do the same problematically (again in windows). My problem is that I have to update the icon of a windows exe file in linux, without using wine.

(the reason for not using wine is that this process should run on an automation server that change the files and sign them).

I don't know even where to start from.

Answer (score -1):

There's a program called [windres](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/windres.html) that should suit your needs

Whoops, that's just a resource compiler, sorry.

However there is [pefile](http://code.google.com/p/pefile/) a python module for working with PE executables, perhaps you could write a script with it that does what you want

Comment: `pefile` seems to be very promising, I'll check it

Comment: Okay, I can't get through the docs of `pefile` I don't understand how to change a resource, but I'll keep looking.

Comment: @zenpoy Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

You can change a files metadata like this:

```
gvfs-set-attribute '/path/to/file' -t stringv metadata::custom-icon "/path/to/image.png"
```

Comment: are your sure that actually swaps out the resource in the file?

Comment: I would say it doesn't :) will check it out

Comment: looks like it stores the metadata in `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/`

Comment: That's what I expected, so it doesn't really solve the problem.