# Set a Windows exe icon from Linux (without Wine ?)

Tags: linux, windows, bash, icons, executable

I'm trying to set a Windows executable icon with a Bash script in Linux, but I can't find anything relevant.

I have found this tool [www.nongnu.org/icoutils](http://www.nongnu.org/icoutils/), but it seems to me that you can only extract .ico file from the executable (then convert it into png), or do the opposite: it takes pngs and it creates an .ico BUT it can't write the new ico into the executable.
Am I right or wrong ? What should I do ?

By the way, I've found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804344/how-to-change-windows-exe-files-icon-in-linux-without-wine) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663778/how-to-change-the-icon-of-a-windows-executable-on-linux-macosx?rq=1), but they do not fully answer the question...

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use [Resource Hacker](http://www.heise.de/download/resource-hacker-1115484.html) with [wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Therefore,

- install `wine`
- download `Resource Hacker`
- install `Resource Hacker` with `wine` (or `wine32` if you are on 64bit):

  ```
  $ wine32 /path/to/reshack_setup.exe
  ```
- change icon:

  ```
  $ wine32 .wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Resource\ Hacker/ResHacker.exe -addoverwrite "oldexe.exe,new.exe,new.ico,ICONGROUP,MAINICON,0"
  ```

  This worked for me on a few `.exe` files. It also failed on one, i don't know why.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It does help, thank you.
But I was really looking for a *NIX way to do it, without Wine and Resource Hacker.

Comment: @Rucikir Have you found a *NIX way to do it?

Comment: @chris13524 no, but Resource Hacker had an update which made scripting it easier. There are interesting Atom packages: [atom/rcedit](https://github.com/atom/rcedit), [atom/node-rcedit](https://github.com/atom/node-rcedit), [unindented/grunt-rcedit](https://github.com/unindented/grunt-rcedit) that should help the process (but require Wine).
You can check https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Icons for more ideas.
Sadly, there are no portable/linux librairies to replace icons in Windows executables.